# Cognos 10.2 SDK: UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, cognos

I have an app which connects to the cognos environment using two jars axis.jar and axisCognosClient.jar

Cognos upgraded it's version from cognos 10.1.1 to cognos 10.2, I have extracted new jar file out of Cognos 10.2 SDK and inlcuded in my project, everything complied successfully but at run time I got the following exception..

```
[6/10/13 13:47:14:609 CDT] 00000028 RequestProces Worg.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor processException Unhandled Exception thrown: class sf.jra.util.reflect.MethodInvocationException
[6/10/13 13:47:14:609 CDT] 00000028 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception thrown in one of the service methods of the servlet: action. Exception thrown : javax.servlet.ServletException: public org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward sf.gds.web.iflex.cognos.actions.CreateReportAction.runReport(org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping,org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) threw a RuntimeException during a reflection invocation.
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:516)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:423)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.WsEJBException: nested exception is: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: (com/cognos/developer/schemas/bibus/_3/AgentService_ServiceLocator) bad major version at offset=6
at com.ibm.ejs.container.LocalExceptionMappingStrategy.mapException(LocalExceptionMappingStrategy.java:229)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.LocalExceptionMappingStrategy.setUncheckedException(LocalExceptionMappingStrategy.java:394)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSDeployedSupport.setUncheckedLocalException(EJSDeployedSupport.java:473)
at sf.gds.service.iflex.ejbs.EJSLocalStatelessCreateReport_dad64636.createReport(EJSLocalStatelessCreateReport_dad64636.java:35)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError
(com/cognos/developer/schemas/bibus/_3/AgentService_ServiceLocator) bad major version    at offset=6
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:577)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:529)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:412)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:605)
at sf.gds.service.iflex.cognos.api.provided.CRNConnect.connectToCognosServer(CRNConnect.java:263)
```

Any idea why do we get this kind of exception.

Comment: What version of java is your Cognos installation using? and what version of java is your app using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your java version for the Cognos installation and the java version used by your app.

For [Cognos 10.1](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.c8pp_inst.10.1.0.doc/c8pp_inst_id17819adv_config_change_JRE_version.html): The current version provided with IBM Cognos BI is JRE 1.5.0.

For [Cognos 10.2](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/documentation/docs/en/10.2.0/inst_cr_winux.pdf): The current version provided with IBM Cognos BI is JRE 6.0.

Comment: Yes, I Cognos 10.2.1 API was compiled with java 6 and my code was compiled with java 5, I recompiled the jar with java 5 and it worked like ac charm!!